# Pyspark - How to calculate a different hash for each value in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, pyspark

I wanted to generate a hash for each value of a column. I've implemented it this way:

```
def generate_hash(df, cols):
    for col in cols:
        df = df.withColumn(col, F.lit(df[col].cast(StringType())))\
               .withColumn(col, F.lit(hashlib.sha256(col.encode()).hexdigest()))
    return df
```

But the function generates the same hash value for every row. How should I fix it to count a hash for each value in a column?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. We can do it without UDF as well. we have inbuilt function for `hash` in spark. you can find more info about it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#hash)

```
    #INPUTDF
    # +------+------+
    # |rec_id|  name|
    # +------+------+
    # |    a1| ricky|
    # |    b1|sachin|
    # +------+------+

    df.select(*[ F.hash(column).alias(column) for column in df.columns]).show()

    #OUTPUTDF
    # +----------+-----------+
    # |    rec_id|       name|
    # +----------+-----------+
    # |2021897151|-2059801476|
    # | 283084925| -576157420|
    # +----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a simple `UDF` for this. I tested your code as an UDF, it works me and creates different hashes.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import hashlib

# simple python function to hash a string 
def hash_column(col_val):
    return hashlib.sha256(col_val).hexdigest()

#register above function as an udf
hashcol_udf = udf(hash_column)

df.withColumn('col1', hashcol_udf(df['col1']))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Loka is the correct one.

Just for complicity I would add that this is a MurMur3 hash with a fixed seed that is 42.

In case you need some more advanced behaviours you can generate your own hash with a different seed by creating a column functions based on Murmur3Hash.

This is just an example how that might look like in scala:

```
new Column(Murmur3Hash(children: _*, seed = 53))
```

Then this can be made available in pyspark by replicating logic from this example file: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py

I am not aware how to directly instantiate Catalyst expressions in python so I proposed this scala way since i usually define all my extensions to spark in scala and port them to pyspark via similar code to the pyspark.sql.functions.py code.

There are also few other hash type methods available in spark.sql

- sha2
- sha1
- md5
- crc32 (even this can be considered a hash operation)